# Double tap necessary to select TableView item with Search Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, uisearchbar

I have a UITableView with a search bar as header.
I use this function to update my data when the user does a search in the search bar.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        if (searchText.characters.count > 0) {
            self.filteredResults  = [];
            self.locationManager?.geocodeAddressString(addressString: searchText, completionHandler: { (results, error) in
                if error == nil && results != nil {
                    self.filteredResults = results!;
                    self.tableView.reloadData();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            self.filteredResults  = [];
            self.tableView.reloadData();
        }
    }
}
```

and this function when I select a cell in my UITableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.delegate?.setCity(city: str);
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Here is my problem : the view controller doesn't dismiss at the first taps on the cell. I taps once, the search bar resign responder. And I need to tap twice for the dismiss to execute.

Here is how I link my tableview and my search bar in viewDidLoad:

```
// Search Bar componants
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil);
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;

self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default;
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("search.city", comment: "search.city").capitalized;

self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .plain);
self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
self.view.addSubview(self.tableView);
```

If someone could help me, that would be great :)

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, if you switch the statements and dismiss the view first, does it work as expected?

Comment: No. I really looks like the first taps just end the search bar editing

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in `didSelectRowAt` does the breakpoint get hit on the first tap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a tap gesture recognizer to your view that when fired would

1. resign the search bar responder
2. convert the tap location to a point in you table view
3. get the cell that tap location
4. manually call `didSelectRowAt` which isn't the "best" solution but for demonstration purposes.

Here is how it looks implemented:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add a tap gesture to our view
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TestTableViewController.didTap(_:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    // Called when the tap gesture fires
    func didTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        // We get rid of our keyboard on screen
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Find the location of the touch relative to the tableView
        let touch = gesture.locationInView(self.tableView)

        // Convert that touch point to an index path
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touch) {

            // Here I am just calling the delegate method directly which you shouldn't do.
            // You should just do whatever you want to do with the indexPath here.
            tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4+ or iOS 10+**

1- Remove searching overlay on viewDidLoad or elsewhere.

```
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

2- In TableView didSelectRowAt delegate add this line.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     searchController.isActive = false
     <your code>
}
```

**..Done..**

Note: with iOS 11+ if you use the SearchController in the navigation item, you will not have this problem. If you present the ViewController with the searchController, just add a new navigation with your ViewController. And present the new navigation instead.

```
UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewControllerWithSearchBar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to ViewDidLoad helped.

searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618656-obscuresbackgroundduringpresenta says

> "If you use the same view controller to display the searchable content
> and search results, it is recommended that you set this property to
> false. The default value of this property is true."

I used the same viewcontroller for searching and displaying. So, setting it to false helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the issue was how I dismissed my ViewController.

Instead of calling dismiss on the UIViewController

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Dismiss the UINavigationController instead to resolve the issue:

```
navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```